# Reading data after writing to it in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to navigate to a specific ID after creating an item in my realtime database.

The documentation offers a solution but it is not working as shown.

After using the push().set() method on my db ref I tried creating a callback function that would get the specific ID created using the push.().set() method and then navigate with that ID.

```
db.ref.push().set({
    ...
}).then(function(){
    router.navigate(ref/ + db.ref.key /)
})
```

After creating a new object at that ref point I want to use the ID created by firebase to navigate to a specific route using that ID.

Comment: So, what library are you using for routing?

Comment: @joelgullander using backbone's router. The issue is not getting back the id after using set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `db.ref.push()` returns a *new* Reference object with the unique id to it. You're not getting the value of that ID. You can refactor things so it would be something like:

```
let newref = db.ref.push();
newref.set({
  ...
})
.then( () => {
  // You can use "newref" here
  // The last part of the full reference path is in "key"
  let id = newref.key;

  // Do something with the id as part of your route
});
```

Comment: This works exactly as I was intending it too. No idea why the documentation was not working. Great answer, thanks for the quick response too!

Answer (score 1):

> set
>
> > **set**(*value*, *onComplete*) => returns firebase.Promise containing void

So you are absolutely correct about that you should be able to see the operation as resolved with a callback however the promise will not give you any key back.

You should however be able to chain this event:

```
db.ref.push().set({
    ...
}).getKey().then(data => console.log(data))
```